# Get value of PrintWriter instead of write in a file

Tags: java

I'm very new using `Java`.
Following a tutorial, I found this method:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();

new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();

PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
stdin.println("\""+tesseract_install_path+"\" \""+file+"\" \""+output_file+"\" -l eng");
stdin.close();
p.waitFor();
```

I'm understanding what the code do, they are executing a command using the cmd.

but, I want to change this:

```
stdin.println("\""+tesseract_install_path+"\" \""+file+"\" \""+output_file+"\" -l eng");
```

and store the value of the result in a viariable, instead of use a file to write.

Is that possible?

Comment: That method is opening that command, and then inputting those values into the process's STDIN, there's nothing in this that interacts with a file, what do you want to do, exactly?

Comment: Get the command output in a variable @zack6849 executing the the file, using as parameter in the CMD the tesseract_install_path and the file (file is the pathfile)

Comment: You could read all the output from stdout into a stringbuilder or something until the process closes and store that in a variable